# Looking for a different logic

Tags: c, ubuntu, codeblocks

so i wrote this unfinished but working code. im a very new to programming and i think that my logic is wrong (although code is running properly) because there is too many "ifs and elses" i cant think of another working logic to insert data to any position of the linked list and output the data + error handling if position is invalid im trying to develop computational thinking
and something tells me this code can be wrote much better

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
   struct node* next;
};

struct node* head = NULL;


void Insert(int c ,int e)
{
    int i;
    static int p = 1;
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp -> data = c;
    temp -> next = NULL;
   struct node* temp1 = head;

    if (e > p+1)
    {
        printf("Invalid Position");
        return;
    }

   else if (head == NULL)
        {
        head = temp;
        return;
        }

    else if (e <= 1)
    {
        temp -> next = head;
        head = temp;
        return;
    }

    else if (e == 2)
    {
        if (temp1 -> next != NULL)
        {
            temp -> next = temp1 -> next;
            temp1 -> next = temp;

        }

        else
        {
            temp1 -> next = temp;

        }

    }

    else
    {
        for (i = 0;i<e-2;i++)
        {
            temp1 = temp1 -> next;
        }

    temp -> next = temp1 -> next;
    temp1 -> next = temp;
    }
p++;
}

void print() {

    struct node* temp = head;
    printf("list is: \n");
    while (temp != NULL) {

        printf( "%d ,",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}


int main () {

printf("How Many Numbers?\n");
int a ,b ,c, e;
scanf("%d" , &b);
for(a = 0;a<b;a++) {
    printf("Enter the numbers \n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    printf("Enter position \n");
    scanf("%d",&e);
    Insert(c , e);
    print();
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest to remove the ubuntu and codeblocks tags as question is not related to any of this. Also, "Enter the numbers" (plural) is misleading as you want 1 number to be entered. Next, there is no punishment if you name your variables well. ``void insert( int value, int position)`` looks a bit better, ,does it not? ``static int p = 1;`` is bad practice. And sooner or later you will want a function ``int length( const struct node* list)`` and your p is then painful. Skipping forward: e is a control flow variable. Fewer ifs: make multiple functions for each case: ``insert_front()``, ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22115254/971127

Comment: This question may be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `insert` function can be simplified a bit. Essentially you have *three* conditions to consider:

> 1. inserting the first node into an empty list;
> 2. inserting a new first node; and
> 3. inserting a new node somewhere between the first and last.

Inserting at the end is the default and requires no special consideration. Coding each of those individually, you could rewrite `insert` as follows:

```
void insert (int c, int e)
{
    struct node *temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);
    if (!temp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    temp->data = c;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (!head) { head = temp; goto check; }  /* empty list */

    struct node *iter = head;

    if (!e) { temp->next = head; head = temp; return; } /* new 1st node */
    for (--e; e && iter->next; iter = iter->next, e--) {}    /* iterate */

    /* inserting before end, update temp->next */
    if (iter->next) temp->next = iter->next;
    iter->next = temp;     /* add node as next */

  check:;
    if (e)
        fprintf (stderr, "warning, 'e' beyond list, inserted at end.\n");
}
```

**note:** `insert` is used instead of `Insert`. C avoids `Caps` and `caMelCase` for variable and function names in favor of all *lower-case*. See e.g. [**NASA - C Style Guide, 1994**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf)

If you are allocating memory for the list, you should keep track of the memory you have allocated so it can be freed when it is no longer needed. Start good habits early, don't simply rely on exit doing it for you. You have already written `print()`, a `delete()` is virtually the same:

```
void delete ()
{
    struct node *tmp = head;
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        struct node *victim = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
        free (victim);
    }
}
```

Putting all the pieces together and cleaning up the remainder of the code a bit, you could rewrite your example as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *head = NULL;

void insert (int c, int e);
void print ();
void delete ();

int main (void) {

    int a, b, c, e, rtn;
    a = b = c = e = rtn = 0;

    printf ("\nDefine list, values and positons (zero based positions)\n\n");
    do {
        printf (" numer of list elements?: ");
        if ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &b)) != 1 || b < 1)
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        if (rtn == EOF) exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    } while (b < 1);

    for (a = 0; a < b; a++) {
        do printf ("\n  number %2d: ", a + 1);
        while ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &c)) != 1 && rtn != EOF);
        if (rtn == EOF) exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

        do printf ("  position : ");
        while ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &e)) != 1 && e >= 0 && rtn != EOF);
        if (rtn == EOF) exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

        insert (c, e);
        print ();
    }
    delete ();
    return 0;
}

void insert (int c, int e)
{
    struct node *temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);
    if (!temp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    temp->data = c;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (!head) { head = temp; goto check; }  /* empty list */

    struct node *iter = head;

    if (!e) { temp->next = head; head = temp; return; } /* new 1st node */
    for (--e; e && iter->next; iter = iter->next, e--) {}    /* iterate */

    /* inserting before end, update temp->next */
    if (iter->next) temp->next = iter->next;
    iter->next = temp;     /* add node as next */

  check:;
    if (e)
        fprintf (stderr, "warning, 'e' beyond list, inserted at end.\n");
}

void print ()
{
    struct node *temp = head;
    printf (" current list is: ");
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf (" %d", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    putchar ('\n');
}

void delete ()
{
    struct node *tmp = head;
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        struct node *victim = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
        free (victim);
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/llins

Define list, values and positons (zero based positions)

 numer of list elements?: 5

  number  1: 6
  position : 0
 current list is:  6

  number  2: 7
  position : 3
warning, 'e' beyond list, inserted at end.
 current list is:  6 7

  number  3: 8
  position : 0
 current list is:  8 6 7

  number  4: 9
  position : 2
 current list is:  8 6 9 7

  number  5: 10
  position : 3
 current list is:  8 6 9 10 7
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: thank you for wroting this logic it helps me alot. im also trying to handle the case when the user input is a character instead of an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can decrease the depth one level by combining two conditions to one:

```
    if (e > p + 1) {
        printf("Invalid Position");
        return;
    }
    else if (head == NULL) {
        head = temp;
        return;
    }
    else if (e <= 1) {
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
        return;
    }
    else if (e == 2 && temp1->next != NULL) {
        temp->next = temp1->next;
        temp1->next = temp;

    }
    else if (temp1->next == NULL) {
        temp1->next = temp;

    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < e - 2; i++) {
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        }
        temp->next = temp1->next;
        temp1->next = temp;
    }
```

Comment: what i meant is this whole logic can be writing diffrently.. i didnt talk about the functions in this code for example : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V42FBiohc6c&list=PL2_aWCzGMAwI9HK8YPVBjElbLbI3ufctn

Answer (score 0):

for sure if and else is not a good pattern design, but you should use it in C. You can change your design when you use an OOP (Object Oriented Programming) language.

In C you should have a modular code so just make smaller parts of code with functions where ever you can.